# Has anything close to video ("live" or otherwise) been shot in space from beyond the Moon?

Tags: rovers, photography, video

It would be cool to see a short video clip of a rover's eye view of driving across mars. Just a few seconds even.

In general, due to limitations in data storage space, bandwidth, and limited duration of line-of-sight access to orbiting spacecraft, rover data that we see is usually a series of still images, each taken at a different key moment.

Just once, has anyone got a hold of a sufficient memory allocation to take a rapid frame rate of images, even once a second, to put together what looks like a GIF or a video of doing something on Mars, or anywhere else beyond the Earth and Moon?

Comment: Inspired by your question i asked this one: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32674/why-not-a-live-visual-connection-with-curiosity-on-mars-all-the-time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on what you consider a "video". Since space probes only take photos, "videos" can be achieved by stitching multiple frames, but then those videos are usually low FPS. Since your title isn't limited to rovers, here are some examples:

Descent of Curiosity on Mars:

Descent of Huygens on Titan:

Jupiter from Voyager (here each frame is one Jupiter day apart, so technically this is also a video?):

And here's a video of an actual rover: Spirit being stuck in the sand on Mars:

Here's the Curiosity timelapse:

Japanese Hayabusa2 collects a sample:

So as you can see, they are mostly timelapses, made from individual photos.

Comment: These are all really excellent! Thank you for finding so many examples and collecting them in one place for others to enjoy.

Comment: I just ran across this: http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/mars/a-day-in-the-life-of-a-rear.html

Comment: Even a "real" video like on a cellphone is a bunch of photos stitched together. The only difference is the phone automatically packs them together into one file and uses video compression. Is packing into one file what counts? Or is it video compression? VHS tapes aren't compressed. Is it just whether it opens in a video player on your computer? Many professional formats won't simply open in Windows Media Player (nor will a VHS tape)