# Are there any images of Curiosity during the sky crane operations?

Tags: mars, curiosity, camera

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32689/20987) has a nice video of Curiosity's descent to MARS. The images come from the [Mars Descent Imager (MARDI)](https://msl-scicorner.jpl.nasa.gov/Instruments/MARDI/), which is mounted on the underside of the rover.

Was there any camera mounted on the sky crane that imaged the rover as it was lowered to the surface?

Comment: Adding the weight of a camera to take images only during the very short phase of sky crane operations?

Comment: @Uwe From the linked page, I understand that MARDI also didn't really serve a science objective or EDL role (as it was descoped and later added again) - seems to me like "nice to have". Even a low-res camera could perhaps have given some insights in how the crane performed in relation to predictions and testing on Earth.

Comment: The images of the MARDI cam during decent helped to identify the landing location on the Mars orbiter images. A camera mounted to the sky crane could not help locating the landing spot.

Comment: Seems they listened ;-)   [Image of Perseverance hanging from the sky crane as it was lowered to the surface](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-s-perseverance-rover-sends-sneak-peek-of-mars-landing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [The  Development  of  the  MSL  Guidance, Navigation, and Control System for Entry, Descent, and Landing](https://trs.jpl.nasa.gov/bitstream/handle/2014/44894/13-0633_A1b.pdf), the sky crane only has the Terminal Descent Sensor (TDS), which only has a doppler radar and no camera.

There are therefore no images of Curiosity during the sky crane operations

[image: sky crane diagram]